# change the text in a span using Jquery

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I want to change the text of below span i.e *Type the Web address:* to *Insert Web address*

```
<span class="ms-formdescription">
Type the Web address: (
<a id="ctl00_m_g_5bbc2ab5_1127_4528_9c7e_448f368ff570_ctl00_ctl05_ctl11_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl0    0_ctl00_UrlControlId" target="_self" 
   href="javascript:TestURL('ctl00_m_g_5bbc2ab5_1127_4528_9c7e_448f36…tl00_ctl05_ctl11_ctl00_c    tl00_ctl04_ctl00_ctl00_UrlFieldUrl')"></a>
)
</span>
```

I tried the following

```
$("span.ms-formdescription:contains('Type the Web address:')").html().replace('Type the Web address:','Insert website address');
```

However its not changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set it again using html function. You have actually get using html() but haven't set it using html().

```
$("span.ms-formdescription:contains('Type the Web address:')").html( $("span.ms-formdescription:contains('Type the Web address:')").html().replace('Type the Web address:','Insert website address'));
```

better code is:

```
var span = $("span.ms-formdescription:contains('Type the Web address:')");
span.html(span.html().replace('Type the Web address:','Insert website address'))
```

Demo is here:
     http://plnkr.co/edit/ZCtf8lgdx54HNtKFhUuJ?p=preview

*Please mark as answer if it answers your question*

Comment: Thanks masum7 it helped its working now i changed it as below   var webAddressHtml =   $("span.ms-formdescription:contains('Type the Web address:')").html().replace('Type the Web address:','Insert website address')
          $("span.ms-formdescription:contains('Type the Web address:')").html(webAddressHtml);